# How to split only digits from a string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have random strings that include 6 integers
example:

- 002500bla
- 025478blu
- 255699bli
- 658896blo

How can I split only the integers from the string in way to have only

- bla
- blu
- bli
- blo

I need to do that using `string.split();`

I tried:

```
int [] test = new int [7];

string.split (test);
```

But it doesn't give any output. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Show us the regex you have tried.

Comment: Simply remove all the digits `str.replaceAll("\\d+","");` output `bla blu bli blo`. Split on the basis of space like this `"bla blu bli blo".split("\\s+")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **String**'s methods [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) together.

```
String s  = "002500bla 025478blu 255699bli 658896blo";
String[] parts = s.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts)); //=> [bla, blu, bli, blo]
```

Comment: use `[0-9]+` instead of [0-9]. your pattern is also correct.

Comment: `replaceAll` will replace an occurrence of so why do you need a quantifier?

Comment: Sorry I have correct it already. It's the same thing that I have commented.

Comment: Sorry I was writing my answer I suppose when you were commenting =)

Answer (score 1):

i hope this help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   String str = "002500bla 025478blu 255699bli 658896blo";
   if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("null str"); 
   }

    //replace all digits
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[0-9]+/*\\.*[0-9]*",""));
    //replace all non-digits
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));

   }
```